# How can I stop mysqldump from specifying the database

Tags: mysql

I'm using `mysqldump --databases db, etc` but it includes lines like `CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`db`/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;` and `USE db`

When I import it it imports it into the original database name but sometimes I want to import it to other databases.

I'd like it to work like Sequel Pro's export where only the tables are exported - the database name isn't mentioned at all.

Are there any relevant command line options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `mysqldump -uYOURUSER -pYOURPASS DBNAME > out.sql` and then restore with `mysql -uYOURUSER -pYOURPASS NEWDBNAME < out.sql`. Notice that I didn't provide `--database` flag.